# How to remove rows from Dataframe based on a group by condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and in that I want to remove all the rows where the user(column) has less than 5 unique values of other column (destination), In general output the rows where user travelled more than 5 unique destination. I used this query `df.groupby(by = ['user_id'])['hotel_country'].nunique()`  to find unique destinations of all rows but when I put condition of less than 5 and try to drop it , it throws an error.

`df.drop(df.groupby(by = ['user_id'])['hotel_country'].nunique() < 5)`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please read this guide on how to format code in questions: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

here we temporarily create a new column in the `DataFrame` that holds the number of unique destinations for this user then make a `Series` of boolean values (mask) to get all the rows which their user has less than 5 destinations and drop them

```py
df.drop(
    df[df.groupby('user_id')['destination'].transform('nunique') < 5].index,
    inplace=True
)
```